# What is the jdbc connection string for h2 database?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-string, h2

I'm trying to connect to an h2 database on my local machine to create a sql DataSource object. I'm running windows and i'm having some issues defining the path to the data file in my projects app.properties file.

Say the path to the local directory data file is:

```
D:\projects\myproject\data\project
```

How would one go about defining a connection url for this?

I've tried the many things including the following:

```
project.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost\\\\D:\\projects\\myproject\\data\\project
```

Then I thought maybe it's the JDBC URL that's the issue, so I tried:

```
project.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp:\\\\localhost\\\\D:\\projects\\myproject\\data\\project
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per **[documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc)**, default `JDBC` connection string is

```
jdbc:h2:~/test
```

And, for TCP connection

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
```

**==Update==**

But, if you wanted to create/read h2 database to/from specific folder, then it should be

```
 jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/<path_to_database>
```

That means,

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/D:/myproject/data/project-name
```

Thanks @Sam for sharing info.

Comment: Hi, that does work, thanks. But it creates the text.db.mv file in my home directory. Ideally i'd want this to be within a file within my project - ie \myproject\data\project

Comment: To save in a folder relative to the project, this would work: `jdbc:h2:./data/`

Answer (score 12):

Change `application.properties` to the following:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.datasource.username=sa

spring.datasource.password=
```

Set H2 Console to the following:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot and don't want to change the default name you can look out for this log statement and copy the JDBC connection info from there:

```
2021-08-31 20:27:13.295  INFO 12032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:4c0a3d2c-9aab-4c06-ab22-da777660ab4a'
```

So in this example the connection string is "**jdbc:h2:mem:4c0a3d2c-9aab-4c06-ab22-da777660ab4a**"