# How to set the jdbc URL for H2 database?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2, flyway

When I try to do the flyway tutorial for Java, I wanted to check the flyway_schema_history table stored in the embedded H2 database. The database file (foobar.mv.db) is created at project target folder with the configuration

```
<url>jdbc:h2:file:./target/foobar</url>
```

But I cannot open the database from browser (localhost:8082). I had to copy the database file to my user home dir because that's the default location that H2 console uses.  How should I specify the jdbc URL in order to have the console pointing to the project target folder? The default URL is jdbc"h2:file:~/foobar. I want to know how to make it point to my project, say at C:\Users\scong\IdeaProjects\my-flyway-migration-service. foobar.mv.db file is created at C:\Users\scong\IdeaProjects\my-flyway-migration-service\target with above configuration.

The answer in the post [What is the jdbc connection string for h2 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409005/what-is-the-jdbc-connection-string-for-h2-database) actually doesn't work for me. The console complains the colon character after the drive letter (C:) in the path. I tried to use the below absolute path,

```
jdbc:h2:file://localhost/C:/Users/scong/IdeaProjects/my-flyway-migration-service/target/foobar
```

It gave the below error
General error: "java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal character [:] in path at index 13: //localhost/C:/Users/scong/IdeaProjects/my-flyway-migration-service/target/foobar" [50000-214] HY000/50000 (Help)

Comment: Try `jdbc:h2:file:C:/Users/scong/IdeaProjects/my-flyway-migration-service/target/foobar`

Comment: Ha, it works with this format. Thanks. @rhowell